# TFS 2015 Alert for Changes in Team/Group send to me

Tags: tfs, alert, tfs-2015

as the title describes i want an alert that sends me an email whenever a change happens to a work item that is assigned to one of my Team Members. Beware this is not a Project Team, it is a specific Group.

As i would understand this: I need an alert under *My Alerts* since only me needs to be informed but when I try the *Assigned to* Field with my group, it doesn't work with *contains* operator and the *in group* operator isn't shown.

Kind Regards
Christian

Comment: You can also try a specialized tool like CatLight notifier to [receive alerts about changes in work item query results](https://catlight.io/a/tfs-work-item-notifications).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*contains* operator means when *Assigned to* Field has the value you specify in filter, the alert will be triggered.

The only way to achieve your requirement is to add multiple **Assigned to** clauses and group them with **Or** like the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Yeah thats a Work around, still its kind of strange because you can make a query for a group but not an alert. Thanks anyway.